# How to define a custom DataStoreHelper in WebSphere 8.5 Liberty Profile

Tags: java, datasource, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

How can I define my own DataStoreHelper in a WebSphere Liberty Profile?

In WebSphere 8 server configuration I'm able to define it under **DataSource => Specify a user-defined data store helper**

[image]

But in a Liberty Profile I don't find any possibility to define this on a DataSource!

My `server.xml` configuration for the DataSource looks like:

```
<dataSource id="HSQLDerbyDatasource" jndiName="jdbc/myConnection" statementCacheSize="10">
    <jdbcDriver javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource" libraryRef="hsqlLib"/>
    <properties.derby.embedded databaseName="${shared.resource.dir}/databases/hsql/myDB" user="foo" password="bar"/>
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="7200" connectionTimeout="180" maxIdleTime="1800" maxPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="1" purgePolicy="EntirePool" reapTime="180"/>
</dataSource>
```

Any ideas? Is it possible at all?

---

**edit 1**

I'm asking, because I want to use an emebdded HSQL-DB which throws the following exception which I want to prevent (because the data fetch is working perfectly except the triggered cleanup at the end):

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: feature not supported
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.notSupported(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.setTypeMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.setTypeMap(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:4762)
    ... 1 more
```

So I tried to extend the `GenericDataStoreHelper` by calling the following code in the constructor:

```
getMetaData().setGetTypeMapSupport(false);
```

But... is there another possibility to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

DataStoreHelper is not supported on the Liberty profile. If there is some functionality that you require, I recommend that you [open a WebSphere RFE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181). I recommend giving the high-level problem you're trying to solve rather than the specific request for DataSourceHelper.

Comment: Thanks for youor answer! I've extended my question with my root cause. Perhaps you can tell me, how I can solve this in another way? :)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information. I discussed with the JDBC team internally at IBM, and they said this problem with setTypeMap is a known issue with the support for generic JDBC providers. They also recommend opening an RFE for better support for generic JDBC providers. The only other alternative would be to write your own proxy layer that no-ops that method, but that's understandably a really big effort.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is you don't need to do so in order to use the HyperSQL driver in Liberty.  After some investigation, the problem you've reported appears to be a bug exposed by the HyperSQL driver not implementing an optional method. A defect has been opened for the issue.  Posting the Liberty version info for future questions will increase the likelihood of an answer.